# Android: disparity between emulator UI and device UI

Tags: android-layout, android-emulator, android

I am working on an android app in which I am seeing some disparity between what is showing up on the actual device and what is showing up when I run the app on the emulator.

Here is the relevant code.

I have an xml file which defines a shape - a simple blue rectangle:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners
        android:radius="4dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="270"
        android:startColor="#449def"
        android:endColor="#2f6699" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#2f6699" />
</shape>
```

I then have another "view" xml file which uses that shape, shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

     <View
         android:background="@drawable/blue_rectangle"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" 
     />

</LinearLayout>
```

Finally, I have a custom ViewGroup which extends RelativeLayout.  This custom layout has a child view object of the view which I described above.  The custom layout also overrides the onLayout method such that it handles the layout process itself.  That code is here:

```
@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) 
{   
    //Layout the children of this viewgroup
    int childCount = this.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++)
    {
        NodeView view = (NodeView) this.getChildAt(i);
        view.layout(40, 40, 40, 40); //Hard code the child object position
    }
}
```

As you can see, I am hardcoding the child views to have position (40, 40) and have width and height of 40 dip.

Unfortunately, I am getting varying results.  This is what it looks like on the Android emulator (part of the Android development tools):

[image: Android emulator output]

This is what it looks like on my actual Android device (and this is what I want it to look like as well):

[image: Android device output]

What is causing the disparity in size of the blue box?  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: What version is the emulator running and what is the device and version of Android running on it?

Comment: Sorry, the device is an LG Optimus V phone running Android 2.2.1.  The emulator is running Android 2.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The emulator has a setting when you make your AVD called Abstracted LCD Density. Make sure that is set to the same as the device. See if that works.

Comment: Thanks!  I created an AVD which mirrors my phone more exactly (320x480 resolution, 180dpi), and it works great.  But how do they expect us to develop for multiple display resolutions?  Both the size of the blue box and the size of each of those white rectangles with orange borders should be 40x40 dip...yet with the other AVD they were different sizes.  How can that be explained?

Comment: this link will help explain it http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html